# Shapefile import used mapbuilder to oracle and publish on Geoserver but can't read '_'(underline)

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial

environment:windows10 and oracle11g

tools:oracle mapbuilder11 and geoserver2.8.2

step:

1.use mapbuilder to shp file into oracle .  like this http://www.duoluodeyu.com/37.html

2.create a link with oracle like this http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/data/database/oracle.html

3.geoserver add this to layer and publish

when i used mapbuilder to shp file into oracle. if the geomatry table name is not have '_'(underline)
[image]

everything is OK

[image]

But if the geomatry table name add '_' like XINZHUANG_2004

geoserver publish result is error ,like this
[image]

i don't know what is going on and I don't ready think it can't add '_'(underline).

I am so sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by myself.

It is the ojdbc.jar package problem

when I was create a link with oracle I need to put the package in geoserver(like d:\GeoServer 2.8.3\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib)

package:gt-jdbc-oracle-14.3.jar and ojdbc

I used ojdbc-14.jar

but I go to the oracle official website to download ojdbc6.jar

it's all right...